# class not found FOP

Tags: java, apache-fop

Hi so i am trying to use FOP to turn an xml file into pdf and i keep on running into errors, right now i have the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlgraphics/io/ResourceResolver
at org.apache.fop.apps.FopConfParser.<init>(FopConfParser.java:122)
at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance(FopFactory.java:132)
at run.ExampleFO2PDF.main(ExampleFO2PDF.java:62)
```

i have the *FOP* library in the build path as well as *xmlgraphics* and *commons logging* and *Avalon framework*

This is the code i am trying to run

```
        import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.OutputStream;

        import javax.xml.transform.Result;
        import javax.xml.transform.Source;
        import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
        import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
        import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
        import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
        import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;
        import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

        import org.apache.fop.apps.*;
        import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

       public class pdf{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, TransformerException
  {
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File("."));
                OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/temp/myfile.pdf")));
                try {
                  Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);
                  TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                  Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(); // identity transformer
                  Source src = new StreamSource(new File("D:/temp/test.xml"));
                  Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
                  transformer.transform(src, res);
                } finally {
                  //Clean-up
                  out.close();
                }
           }

    }
```

Comment: Please show us how you're *running* the code. It looks like you haven't got xmlgraphics in the classpath.

Answer (score 5):

```
abstract interface org.apache.fop.apps.MimeConstants implements org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.MimeConstants
```

`org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.MimeConstants` belong to **xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar**. Just include **xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar** in your classpath, it will resolve the issue.

Comment: According to the question, the missing class is `org/apache/xmlgraphics/io/ResourceResolver`.  This is _not_ contained in `xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar`, so including this jar will _not_ fix  OP's problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you've figured out this one - but anyway for those that haven't:
The trunk of FOP 1.1 does have the FopConfParser which references the xmlgraphics.io.ResourceResolver

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlgraphics/fop/trunk/src/java/org/apache/fop/apps/FopConfParser.java?view=markup

and the trunk of xmlgraphics commons does have the ResourceResolver:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlgraphics/commons/trunk/src/java/org/apache/xmlgraphics/io/ResourceResolver.java?view=log

So as a solution, update to trunk! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Really old thread, but i takes me so long to resolve this, so for migration from FOP 1.1 to 2.0 made this change in pom like this:

from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId> 
    <artifactId>fop</artifactId> 
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to:

```html
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>                  
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
                </exclusion>  
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>batik-svg-dom</artifactId>
                </exclusion>  
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
                </exclusion>  
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>batik-awt-util</artifactId>
                </exclusion>  
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>batik-gvt</artifactId>
                </exclusion>  
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
                </exclusion>  
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>batik-extension</artifactId>
                </exclusion>  
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>batik-ext</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-svg-dom</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-awt-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-gvt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-extension</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you describe what you changed? A change involves a movement from one point to another. I only see the result of your change. It would be nice to see a delta.

Comment: Sorry, i thought that its obvious, `<groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>`

Comment: To finish this topic, i also changed fopFactory creation - from: `FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
  fopFactory.setStrictValidation(false);
        fopFactory.getFontManager();` to `FopFactoryBuilder builder = new FopFactoryBuilder(new File(".").toURI());
        builder.setStrictFOValidation(false);
        FopFactory fopFactory = builder.build();`

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, adding a bit more for completeness.

I ran in to a similar problem when updating to FOP 1.1 from 0.92b with the MimeConstants class not being found.

I resolved it by using the xmlgraphics-commons version in the source distribution of FOP version that I was using.

Try using the xmlgraphics-commons jar that was used when your version of FOP was built, which can be found in the lib folder in the FOP source distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an `xmlgraphics` jar, but I did find [xmlgraphics-commons](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/xmlgraphics-commons). Is that what you meant?

From the page I linked above it would seem that it doesn't contain a `org.apache.xmlgraphics.io` package, but it does contain `org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.io`. Maybe you meant that one?